# Find which class opens a port

Tags: java

We have several java applications running on nodes in a cluster. They either use tomcat or jetty, and we configure them to use specific ports. We also configure JMX to use specific ports, both the `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` and the `com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port` (we even limit these to a specific network interface), so a typical server should have 3 ports open (http, https and jmx).

We find that all our services have *4* ports open, and running them under  `strace` confims *someone* opens a ramdom port on all interfaces:

```
bind(210, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
```

I tried to connect with jconsole to this port but I got an error:

```
error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset[...]
```

and the rest of the error fly away from the border of jconsole's connect window :(

So my question is, is there a way to find the class or a stack trace that would point to the class that opens this socket?

Comment: (1) Set breakpoints on `ServerSocketFactory`? If you don't have a proper debugger, `jdb` can handle something this simple. (2) As another approach, instead of `jconsole` connect with a more basic tool like `telnet netcat socat` or `cat </dev/tcp/$addr/$port` (depending on OS or bash) and see what, if anything, it outputs.

Comment: You may try to identify the thread waiting on "accept()" on that socket by running `jstack $pid`, and analyze the stack-trace.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I tried with `jdb` and `stop in java.net.Socket.bind`, but somehow it didn't stop there. What I can see is `RMI TCP Accept-19084` and `RMI TCP Accept-0` in the list of threads, so maybe it's that?

Comment: Maybe you can look up what usually runs on that port? Port 210 seems to be [Z39.50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z39.50).

Comment: It's not port 210, it's file descriptor 210. The port is random, based on `sin_port=htons(0)`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yeah, no, no generic plain text client gives any info, neither `curl` using http or https protos.

Comment: Often (maybe usually) code doesn't call `ServerSocket.bind` explicitly, especially for 0, but uses a `ServerSocket` ctor (which I forgot, add those) or `ServerSocketFactory.create*` method that binds implicitly. `Socket.bind` is used only for initiating connections (and rarely at that) not for listening which is what you mean by 'open'. HTTP and HTTPS are about as complex as JMXRMI, and don't count as basic, but if a basic method shows nothing then it's not any listener-first protocol.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 does that mean that `jdb` won't dive into the standard library and find the underlying call to `Socket.bind()`?

Comment: I was assuming they might do direct calls or even be native, but on checking only the 'Impl' classes use native not the API (makes sense) and the `ServerSocket` ctors _do_ go through the `bind(SocketAddress,int)` method, so yes setting one breakpoint there (_not_ `Socket.bind` which is different) works.